# Apps Similar to Nodebox?

Tags: python, nodebox

I'm looking for apps/environments similar to [Nodebox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Tutorial). Nodebox is so cool and I want to know if there were other similar apps out there.

They don't have to be graphics-related; I'm interested in software that uses programming languages in a new way.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why do I see "Nodebox" and think of Postscript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://processing.org/ is a language for creating graphics and animations similar to Nodebox.

Answer (score 0):

it was referenced on @Jonas processing.org, but [alice.org](http://www.alice.org/) is interesting.